# error condition "user not found" on twitter with python

Tags: python, database, twitter, tweepy

I want to find user identity in twitter from their username which the data is already saved on my database

I made a condition like this

```
#get data from database
cur.execute("SELECT user FROM `rt6`")
row = cur.fetchall()

for text in row:
    #Get Identity of BMKG in Twitter
    user = api.get_user(text)
    try:
        print ("Name:", user.name)
        print ("Name:", user.screen_name)
        print ("Number of tweets: " + str(user.statuses_count))
        print ("followers_count: " + str(user.followers_count))
        print ("Account location: ", user.location)
        print ("Account created at: ", user.created_at)
        print ("Account geo enabled: ", user.geo_enabled)
    except ValueError:
        print("user not found")
```

and my target is when the user not found with one of the usernames on my database, just skip to the next row on the database.

[image]

and I got an error like this, anyone could solve my problem?

Comment: you need to handle the exact exception class which in this case is `tweepy.error.TweepError`  or one that this exception class subclasses if you needed to handle exceptions that subclasses it.

Comment: could you give me an example bro? @OluwafemiSule

I tried changed "ValueError" to "tweepy.error.TweepError" and its still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown from the `api.get_user(...)` call.  But you're not handling exceptions thrown by that line.  You're only handling exceptions thrown by any of the `print` statements below it.  Let me clarify that by adding some comments to your code:

```
for text in row:
    #Get Identity of BMKG in Twitter
    user = api.get_user(text) ### Exception thrown on this line

    try:   ### Exception handling starts here
        print ("Name:", user.name)
        print ("Name:", user.screen_name)
        print ("Number of tweets: " + str(user.statuses_count))
        print ("followers_count: " + str(user.followers_count))
        print ("Account location: ", user.location)
        print ("Account created at: ", user.created_at)
        print ("Account geo enabled: ", user.geo_enabled)
    except ValueError:
        print("user not found")
```

Try moving the call to `api.get_user` within the `try` block.  I've also adjusted the exception being caught, as suggested in the comments:

```
for text in row:
    try:
        #Get Identity of BMKG in Twitter
        user = api.get_user(text)
        print ("Name:", user.name)
        print ("Name:", user.screen_name)
        print ("Number of tweets: " + str(user.statuses_count))
        print ("followers_count: " + str(user.followers_count))
        print ("Account location: ", user.location)
        print ("Account created at: ", user.created_at)
        print ("Account geo enabled: ", user.geo_enabled)
    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        print("user not found")
```

Comment: alhamdulillah. I get it. I must insert the define code into try to make exception work. thank you bro, it is really great :D